# How to access vuex store with factory function pattern

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, factory-pattern

I inherited an app which is bootstrapped in a way that is rather perplexing to me (unlike like the docs or anything I have seen), my task is to create a global loader instead of implementing on each page separately.
I thought this would be simple where I could just manage the state in the store and have a shared "Header" component respond to changes in the "loading" property in the store. Boy was I wrong, it seems as though the way the app is setup with factories I don't have access to the store inside my interceptor.
The code is a bit advanced for me and I would be very appreciative if anyone can explain either how to restructure the code or alternatively how to access the store inside the interceptor.

### My `main.js` looke like this:

```
import 'babel-polyfill' // IE support
import cssVars from 'css-vars-ponyfill'; // css variables support for IE
import 'innersvg-polyfill'; // svg support for IE
// until here, all polyfills

import "vue-material-design-icons/styles.css";

import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import {localizationFactory} from "./localization";
import {apiFactory, apiPluginFactory} from './api/api';
import {storeFactory} from "./store/store";
import {configServiceFactory} from "./services/configService";

import {Services, Security, Utils} from 'em-common-vue';

import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import {filtersFactory} from './filters/index';

const appsService = new Services.appsService(process.env);
const loginDetails = {
    loginHost: appsService.getLoginStorage()
};
console.log("top of main.js before factory functions", this)
Security.ServiceFactory(loginDetails).then($security => {
    console.log("inside secutiy service factor 'then'", this)
    Vue.config.productionTip = false;

    Vue.use(Utils.EventBusPlugin);
    Vue.use($security);

    var vInstance = new Vue();
    const $api = apiFactory(vInstance, $security);

    configServiceFactory($security, $api).then($config => {
        Vue.use($config);
        Vue.use( apiPluginFactory($api) );

        // for now
        const store = storeFactory($api, null);

        Vue.use(VueI18n);

        filtersFactory($config.$service);

        localizationFactory($config.$service).then(messages => {

            const i18n = new VueI18n({
                locale: 'en', // set locale
                messages, // set locale messages
            });

            new Vue({
                router,
                store,
                i18n,
                render: h => h(App),

                computed: {

                    title: {
                        set(val) {
                            document.querySelector('title').innerText = val;
                        },
                        get(val) {
                            return document.querySelector('title').innerText;
                        }
                    }
                },

                mounted() {
                    cssVars({
                        silent: false, // default,
                        watch: true,
                        onWarning() {
                            console.log("onWarning",arguments); // 1
                        },
                        onError() {
                            console.log("onError", arguments); // 1
                        }
                    });

                    if (!document.querySelector('title')) {
                        let title = document.createElement('title');
                        document.head.append(title);
                    }

                    this.title = this.$config.get().title;
                }
            }).$mount('#app')
        });
    });

}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);

    if (err.loginUrl) {
        const nextUrl = appsService.getLogin(window.location.href);
        window.location.href = nextUrl;
    } else { // for now
        alert(err);
    }
});
```

### The `apiFactory` which is where the interceptor resides looks like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

import {UsersApi} from "./usersApi";
import {PartnersApi} from "./partnersApi";
import {TrialsApi} from "./trialsApi";

export function apiFactory(vue, $security) {
    console.log("inside api factory")
    console.log(this)
    const $http = axios.create({
        baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
    });

    $http.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
        console.log("inside interceptor ", this)
        // this.$store.commit('toggleLoader')
        const token = $security.loginFrame.getToken();

        if (token) {
            config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }

        return config;

    }, function (error) {
        vue.$eventBus.$emit('toastMessageHandler', {message: error.message, type: 'error'});
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });

    $http.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {

        return response;

    }, function (error) {
        if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {

            vue.$eventBus.$emit('authErr', error);
        } else if (error.response && error.response.status === 403) {
            alert('You are not authorized to access this application. If you believe you are seeing this message in error, please contact support@emergingmed.com.');
        }

        else if (error.response && error.response.status !== 409){
            vue.$eventBus.$emit('toastMessageHandler', {message: error.message, type: 'error'});
        }
        else if (error.response && error.response.status === 500){
            vue.$eventBus.$emit('toastMessageHandler', {message: 'There was a problem with this operation - please contact support@emergingmed.com.', type: 'error'});
        }

        return Promise.reject({error});
    })

    const $api = {
        users: new UsersApi($http),
        partners: new PartnersApi($http),
        trials: new TrialsApi($http)
    };

    return $api;
}

// register $api as vue plugin
export function apiPluginFactory($api) {
    return {
        install(vue) {
            vue.prototype.$api = $api;
        },
    };
}
```

When I try to run this code **`this.$store.commit('toggleLoader')`** (commented out in the actual code) I get an error that `store` is undefined. In general this structure does not seem to me idiomatic to vue (or maybe even JS) but I am not sure how I would restructure it.
1)How might I access my store in the interceptor code?
2)How might the app be restructured?

Comment: Since you're already passing the vue instance anyway, couldn't you access the $store via the prototype, just like you're later adding the $api to it?

Comment: I cant since the prototype does not contain the store at that point.